# Object resurrection when using C callbacks from Swift

Tags: swift, memory, callback, reference-counting

I'm trying to access a C API from Swift that requires the use of C callbacks.

```
typedef struct {
    void * info;
    CFAllocatorRetainCallBack retain;
    CFAllocatorReleaseCallBack release;
} CFuncContext;

typedef void (* CFuncCallback)(void * info);

CFuncRef CFuncCreate(CFuncCallback callback, CFuncContext * context);

void CFuncCall(CFuncRef cfunc);

void CFuncRelease(CFuncRef cfunc);
```

`CFuncCreate` stores the callback and context on the heap (using malloc), then calls the `retain` callback to retain the info pointer. `CFuncCall` simply invokes the callback for demonstration purposes, and `CFuncRelease` calls the `release` callback, then frees the memory.

---

In the Swift code I want to use a dedicated object for `info` that keeps a weak reference back to my main object. When the main object is `deinit`ed, `CFuncRelease` is called to also clean up the C API memory.

This way, even if the C API decides to perform some delayed callbacks from different run loops, it always has a valid `info` pointer until it decides to invoke the `release` callback when it is finally done. Just some defensive programming :)

The `info` object has this structure:

```
final class CInfo<T: AnyObject> {
    /// This contains the pointer back to the main object.
    weak private(set) var object: T?

    init(_ object: T) {
        self.object = object
    }

    /// This variable is used to hold a temporary strong 
    /// `self` reference while retainCount is not 0.
    private var context: CInfo<T>?

    /// Number of times that `retain` has been called
    /// without a balancing `release`.
    private var retainCount = 0 {
        didSet {
            if oldValue == 0 {
                context = self
            }
            if retainCount == 0 {
                context = nil
            }
        }
    }

    func retain() {
        ++retainCount
    }

    func release() {
        --retainCount
    }
}
```

---

My main object `SwiftObj` uses the C API.

```
final class SwiftObj {
    typealias InfoType = CInfo<SwiftObj>

    private lazy var info: InfoType = { InfoType(self) }()

    private lazy var cFunc: CFuncRef = {
        var context = CFuncContext(
            info: &self.info,
            retain: { UnsafePointer<InfoType>($0).memory.retain(); return $0 },
            release: { UnsafePointer<InfoType>($0).memory.release() }
        )

        return CFuncCreate(
            /* callback: */ cFuncCallback,
            /* context: */ &context
        )
    }()

    func call() {
        CFuncCall(cFunc)
    }

    deinit {
        CFuncRelease(cFunc)
    }

    init() {
        call()
    }
}

func cFuncCallback(info: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
    print("==> callback from C")
}
```

---

In my testing code, I first allocate a `SwiftObj` via an IBAction. Then, I set the reference back to `nil` again via a second IBAction.

The automated cleanup code should now properly deinit the `SwiftObj`, and from there the C API should be notified that it should clean up its memory. Then, the `release` callback on the `info` pointer should be invoked, which results in the `info` pointer's reference count reaching zero, and also deallocating the `info` pointer.

**However**, the deinit theory doesn't seem to work out. After `SwiftObj`'s final reference is removed, another reference is added back when the `release` callback closure is invoked, and another reference is re-added during the `CInfo.release` method (as observed using Instrument's Allocations tracker). Behaviour also depends on the timings - e.g. the number of log statements.

With a minimal sample like the one below, it crashes immediately in the initial `release` callback closure with either of these two messages depending on the timings - first one is more common, second one can be achieved by a fast space tab space if you are lucky. Maybe there's even more - as I said, in my full example if you put in enough log statements sometimes it prolongs the final cleanup of the `SwiftObj` enough so that you can see the actual resurrection happening.

- EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
- EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)

---

Minimal example can be downloaded here:

- https://scriptreactor.com/Resurrection.zip

Run, then hit the Start button, then hit the Stop button. Welcome to the nightmare.

Instruments' Allocations view can also be quite interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a compiler bug. Workaround is to remove the lazy attribute of the info instance variable.

https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-74